# How to customize adapter to limit items to display

Tags: java, android

My app is using an adapter to show objects, I want to limit it so that only the first 10 items is shown

Here is the code I am using

```
public void onResponse(TopScoreObject[] response) {
            try {
                if(response != null){
                    List<TopScoreObject> mList = arrayToListObject(response);
                    Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<TopScoreObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(TopScoreObject topScoreObject, TopScoreObject t1) {
                            return Integer.parseInt(topScoreObject.getScores()) - Integer.parseInt(t1.getScores());
                        }
                    });
                    Collections.reverse(mList);
                    mAdapter = new LadderBoardAdapter(mList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

By default it shows all the items in list but I only want to show first 10 of it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the first 10 items and the user can scroll to see the next set of items?

Comment: No just want to show 10 thats it

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void onResponse(TopScoreObject[] response) {
        try {
            if(response != null){
                ArrayList<TopScoreObject> mList = arrayToListObject(response);
                if(mList.size() > 10)
                    mList.subList(10, mList.size()).clear();

                Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<TopScoreObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(TopScoreObject topScoreObject, TopScoreObject t1) {
                        return Integer.parseInt(topScoreObject.getScores()) - Integer.parseInt(t1.getScores());
                    }
                });
                Collections.reverse(mList);
                mAdapter = new LadderBoardAdapter(mList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just loop through your list and remove elements greater than index 9?

```
while(mList.size() > 10) {
     mList.remove(10);
}
```

Comment: please tell me how can I do that